# How to include dead times into the model of the three-phase voltage source inverter?

Tags: power-electronics, pwm, inverter, three-phase, modeling

I have been developing a *Scilab* model of the three-phase voltage source inverter. I have started with the idealized model where I suppose that in each of the inverter leg one transistor can be turned on immediately after the other is turned off, i.e. I have neglected the dead times. This idealized model is based on the equations given below for the star-connected three-phase load:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
v_{an} &=& \frac{2\cdot S_1 - S_2 - S_3}{3}\cdot v_{dc} \\
v_{bn} &=& \frac{-S_1 + 2\cdot S_2 - S_3}{3}\cdot v_{dc}\\
v_{cn} &=& \frac{-S_1 - S_2 + 2\cdot S_3}{3}\cdot v_{dc}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where the \$v_{an}, v_{bn}, v_{cn}\$ are the phase voltages, the \$S_1, S_2, S_3\$ are the switching
signals for the upper transistors in the individual legs of the inverter, and \$v_{dc}\$ is the current value of the dc link voltage.

The output of the idealized inverter model is the following: (\$v_{an}, i_a\$) (\$f_{mod} = 100\,\mathrm{Hz}, f_{pwm} = 3000\,\mathrm{Hz}, t_{dt} = 0\,\mu\mathrm{s}, R = 1.0\,\Omega, L = 5.0\,\mathrm{mH}\$)

[image]

As a second step I would like to improve the idealized model of the inverter and I would
like to include also the dead times. My idea how to do that is summarized by the steps given below:

1. implement delayed turning-on signals for the transistors in the individual inverter legs
2. take into account the polarity of the current in the individual inverter legs

As far as the delay for the turning-on signals I have chosen the following approach:

[image]

(black ~ Sx_High, green ~ Sx_Low)

[image]

For the polarity of the current in the inverter legs I have implement a *Scilab* function with the following code:

```
function Sx = InverterLeg(HiSwitchState, LoSwitchState, ix)
    if HiSwitchState == 1 & LoSwitchState == 0 then
        Sx = 1;
    elseif HiSwitchState == 0 & LoSwitchState == 1 then
        Sx = 0;
    elseif HiSwitchState == 0 & LoSwitchState == 0 then
        if ix > 0 then
           Sx = 0;
        else
           Sx = 1;
        end
    end
endfunction
```

I have integrated the signals delay and inverter current polarity into my idealized model and I have received following phase current:
(\$f_{mod} = 100\,\mathrm{Hz}, f_{pwm} = 3000\,\mathrm{Hz}, t_{dt} = 40\,\mu\mathrm{s}, R = 1.0\,\Omega, L = 5.0\,\mathrm{mH}\$).

[image]

My question:

1. I am not able to explain the strange behavior of the phase current at the beginning of the simulation.

[image]

2. Similarly, I am not able to explain the strange behavior of the phase current around its amplitudes.

[image]

Comment: In question 2 when you say "amplitude" you mean "peak" right? What do you find strange? Can you annotate the picture with a circle around the part you find strange or add more explanation to the text? What I find strange is that it appears to me that the current ramps downward when the high side switch is on. In the simulation, is this "steady state" mechanically, or is the motor accelerating against inertia or???

Comment: @mkeith thank you for your reaction. Yes, you are correct I mean amplitude as a synonym for peak. As far as the simulation. I have basically simulated the transient after connection of simple RL load to the inverter. The strange behavior of the current is as you have mentioned the current decrease during the time period when the high side switch is on. This behavior is more pronounced in the circled regions.

Comment: I am not too sure. Maybe you can try reducing the simulation time step value?

Comment: @Steve Check all the signals, from all three branches, when digging around the glitches. Since it's a 3-phase, any two phases will interact in one way, or another. Those could be overlapping pulses and, if so, you may need to rearrange your timings / PWM generation.

Comment: The rising and falling of the current waveform does not seem to coincide with the high and low of the gate pulses. Investigating the path between would seem illuminating.